# How can I wrap contiguous sibling divs under a parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<p>Some Text</p>
<div class="listBullet">Item 1</div>
<div class="listBullet">Item 2</div>
<div class="listBullet">Item 3</div>
<p>Some More Text</p>
<div class="listBullet">Item 1</div>
<div class="listBullet">Item 2</div>
<div class="listBullet">Item 3</div>
<p>Some Other Text</p>
```

I want to end up with the following output:

```
<p>Some Text</p>
<div class="wrapperDiv">
   <div class="listBullet">Item 1</div>
   <div class="listBullet">Item 2</div>
   <div class="listBullet">Item 3</div>
</div>
<p>Some More Text</p>
<div class="wrapperDiv">
   <div class="listBullet">Item 1</div>
   <div class="listBullet">Item 2</div>
   <div class="listBullet">Item 3</div>
</div>
<p>Some Other Text</p>
```

I tried `$(".listBullet").wrapAll("<div class='wrapperDiv' />")`, but that ended up moving the two blocks to be contiguous with each other. It seems like what I need is a selector that separates the contiguous blocks into separate elements, which I would then call wrapAll on separately.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This does the job:

```
$('p + .listBullet').each(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil('p')
         .addBack()
         .wrapAll("<div class='wrapperDiv' />");
});
```

[**Fiddle 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/wcf6zLtd/11)

---

If your XHTML has a mix of elements, you can do this (assuming `container` is the class of the parent `div`):

```
$('.container > :not(.listBullet) + .listBullet').each(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil('.container > :not(.listBullet)')
         .addBack()
         .wrapAll("<div class='wrapperDiv' />");
});
```

[**Fiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/wcf6zLtd/10)

---

Here's a more brute force approach:

```
var lb= [];
$('.container > *').each(function() {
  if($(this).hasClass('listBullet')) {
    lb.push(this);
  }
  else {
    $(lb).wrapAll("<div class='wrapperDiv'/>");
    lb= [];
  }
});
$(lb).wrapAll("<div class='wrapperDiv'/>");
```

[**Fiddle 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/71qfdd4r/3)

Comment: Just curious, why the `+` in `$('p + .listBullet')`? Is that different than `$('p .listBullet')`?

Comment: @JasonTowne it' a "sibling" selector.  The OP's entire problem is that the all the original elements are siblings, with nothing to group the 2 sets of divs.   If there were, this would be trivial.

Comment: The latter will select `.listbullet` that is a child of `p`. The former will select `.listbullet` that's a sibling of `p`

Comment: @Alnitak is right.  Without the +, the selector will look for children of the `p` tag.

Comment: re: fiddle 2 - don't forget to allow for the case when `lb` still has stuff left over at the end of the loop...

Answer (score 3):

As a general approach you could:

Loop through all the elements on the page using `.next()`, while the next element you find is has the correct class, (use `.attr("class")`) add an extra class of `currentList` (or simular) class wrapAll on `currentList` then select all the items with the `currentList` class and remove that class and then keep looping!

Comment: Yeah, that's where I was headed...I was going to see if there was a shortcut.

Comment: I wracked my brains and couldn't think of one... You could of course write yourself a little library function to do exactly this which you could then recycle any time you need it :-) #codeReuse

Answer (score 2):

Well, *you could also do something like this*, although maybe just using jQuery methods is more straightforward (and a bit more flexible):

http://jsfiddle.net/ewj44a2L/1/

```js
var listBullets = $('.listBullet'),
    n = 3, // Number of bullets per group. All groups must be equal.
    len = listBullets.length / n; // Number of groups to be encapsulated
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    listBullets.slice( n * i, n * (i + 1) )
    .wrapAll('<div class="wrapperDiv"></div>');
}
```

```css
.wrapperDiv {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Some Text</p>
<div class="listBullet">Item 1</div>
<div class="listBullet">Item 2</div>
<div class="listBullet">Item 3</div>
<p>Some More Text</p>
<div class="listBullet">Item 1</div>
<div class="listBullet">Item 2</div>
<div class="listBullet">Item 3</div>
<p>Some Other Text</p>
<div class="listBullet">Item 1</div>
<div class="listBullet">Item 2</div>
<div class="listBullet">Item 3</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```js
$("p").map(function(i, el) {
  var el = $(el), list = ".listBullet";
  if (el.next().is(list)) {
    var wrap = el.after("<div class=wrapperDiv />").next();
    do { wrap.next().appendTo(wrap); } 
    while (wrap.next().is(list));
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<p>Some Text</p>
   <div class="listBullet">Item 1</div>
   <div class="listBullet">Item 2</div>
   <div class="listBullet">Item 3</div>
<p>Some More Text</p>
   <div class="listBullet">Item 1</div>
   <div class="listBullet">Item 2</div>
   <div class="listBullet">Item 3</div>
<p>Some Other Text</p>
```